# Azure Mobile Services logs

Tags: c#, logging, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services with .NET backend and I am trying to find a way to access the error logs. I know that I can access the log from the portal, but it only has the last 20 records. I also tried from the Visual Studio Server Explorer and Kudu and in both cases I see the same 20 records.

Is there any way to access more records or full log from the portal?
Is there any other way to access full log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the destination of the logs to somewhere you can access later, such as a table in Azure storage.

For more details, see the "Changing logs destination" part of this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/24/logging-with-the-net-backend-for-azure-mobile-services.aspx